# Does `npm install` support concurrent runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, concurrency, npm

I cannot find information about this. Are concurrent runs of `npm install` supported, or are they going to conflict on some shared resource, or generate some race condition?

Knowing this by analysing the code might be hard, but surely for people developing `npm` this is an implicit assumption

Answer (score 0):

We are continuously running multiple builds on our Jenkins server which all invoke `npm install`. As far as I know there were no issues regarding concurrent npm installs.

As concurrent npm installs may me ok in our case, I don't know if there might be some specific configurations that may cause some trouble.